# Fit one matrix into another in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix A[72][36] and I would like to fit the values of A in a bigger matrix B[360][180].

I constructed this data frame linking the col/row index of A to the new 'grid'.

```
> head(INDEX)
    LonNew LatNew LonINT LatINT 
1   -179.5  -89.5      1      1 
2   -178.5  -88.5      1      1  
3   -177.5  -87.5      1      1  
4   -176.5  -86.5      1      1  
5   -175.5  -85.5      1      1  
6   -174.5  -84.5      2      2  
7   -173.5  -83.5      2      2  
8   -172.5  -82.5      2      2   
9   -171.5  -81.5      2      2   
10  -170.5  -80.5      2      2
```

Then I calculated the corresponding values of the new Lat/Lon couples

```
NEWVar <- array(NA, dim = length(INDEX$LonNew))
for (j in 1:length(INDEX$LonINT) ){
    NEWVar[j] <- A[INDEX$LonINT[j],INDEX$LatINT[j]]
}

> head(NEWVar)

3 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4
```

The problem is then that I don't know how to create the new 360x180 matrix where for each couple (LonNew,LatNew) I have the corresponding NEWVar.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: can you post your code, along with the expected behaviour/results and actual results?

Comment: I'm still confused by how this INDEX should work. Or how you got values into NEWVar when you created it with NA. Where did those 3's and 4's come from? Maybe rather than doing a full 72x36 matrix, you could create a smaller scale problem where. Maybe A is 2x2 and B is 5x5 so we can better see what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Philip that second link doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a smaller, complete reproducible example. Here's the smaller matrix.

```
A<-matrix(1:4, nrow=2)
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]    1    3
# [2,]    2    4
```

And let's say you want to scale that up to a 5x5 using this index.

```
INDEX<-data.frame(
   LonNew = rep(c(-2,-2,0,2,2), each=5),
   LatNew = rep(c(-2,-2,0,2,2), 5),
   LonInt = rep(c(1,1,1,2,2), each=5),
   LatInt = rep(c(1,1,2,1,2), 5)
)
```

The easiest way to turn the new values of Lat and Lon into array indexes is via factor variables. So i created

```
NNF <- factor(INDEX$LonNew)
TNF <- factor(INDEX$LatNew)
```

And i create the new B matrix with

```
B<-matrix(NA, nrow=nlevels(NNF), ncol=nlevels(TNF), 
    dimnames=list(levels(NNF), levels(TNF)))
```

And then I do the assignment with

```
B[cbind(NNF, TNF)] <- A[cbind(INDEX$LonInt, INDEX$LatInt)]
```

and that returns

```
#    -2 0 2
# -2  1 3 3
# 0   1 3 3
# 2   2 4 4
```

which has scaled up the matrix according to the index data. The trick here was just index our matrices with matrices so we can grab different row and column values each time.

Comment: I can't make it work for non quadratic matrices and also I don't understand how can I use it for my problem

Comment: I'm not sure how being quadratic would make a difference. How is your data different than my sample? The INDEX table should be doing all the work.

Comment: OK sorry so maybe I am not understanding something. How are you creating LonInt and LatInt?

Comment: Also if I do                                                       INDEX<-data.frame(
+    LonNew = rep(c(-2,-1,0,1,2), each=5),
+    LatNew = rep(c(-1,0,1),each=3)
+ )                                                            
Error in data.frame(LonNew = rep(c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2), each = 5), LatNew = rep(c(-1,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 25, 9

Comment: I was just creating a sample INDEX mapping. I was assuming you would use the one you created. It should gives the x,y values for B in the first two columns, and the x,y index values for A in the second. YOu can do the mapping however you like. But for your sample just above, it would more like  `LonNew = rep(c(-2,-1,0,1,2), each=3), + LatNew = rep(c(-1,0,1),each=5)` so they are the same length in the end. But again, my method doesn't require you to change your INDEX data.frame. Just what you do with it after, starting with the factor conversion.

Comment: OK, thanks I was making a mistake in the creation of INDEX! Thanks